# cows and bulls methods

Tags: java, methods

I'm not sure if anyone is familiar with the game cows and bulls. Basically I'm trying to write a method that is a user enters in a number of 1234 and another user enters in 4305 this will give them 2 cows because the numbers are in the first number but in the wrong index. If they are in the same index then they get a bull. I must call methods that I have previously coded. I have it to where it counts the number of correct numbers found in the first number given but I can't figure out how to get it to NOT count them if they are in the same index. Any advice would be great.

```
public static int numDigits(int number)
{
    int counter = 0;
    while(number !=0)
    {
        int digit = number % 10;
        number= number /10;
        counter++;
    }
    return counter;
}

public static int getDigit(int number, int i)
{
    int negative =-1;
    int counter = 0;
    int digit = 0;
    if(i>numDigits(number)|| i == 0)
    {

        return negative;
    }
        while(counter < i)
        {
         digit = number % 10;
        number = number / 10;
        counter++;

        }   

    return digit;
}
public static int indexOf (int number, int digit)
{
    int counter = 0;
    int negative = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i<=numDigits(number); i++)
    {
        counter++;
        if(getDigit(number,i)== digit)
        {
            return counter-1;
        }
    }
    return negative;
}
public static int getCows(int first, int second)
{
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<numDigits(first); i++)
    {
        if(getDigit(first,i)==getDigit(second,i))
        {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry about the way it looks on here. I have problems getting it to look like it should if anyone would like to edit.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking how to not count the bulls as cows?

```
public static int getCows(int first, int second)
{
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<numDigits(first); i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; i<numDigits(second); j++)
        {
            if(j!=i && getDigit(first,i)==getDigit(second,j) )
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I will have to write a method after this one to only count bulls but I figured if I can understand how to get this one done then I can do the bull method.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not understanding what you are trying to do here. Why is the && at the end of the if statement?

Comment: The problem with this answer (apart from that weird `&&`) is that if two of the cows are the same number, it will count them twice.  For example, `1123` compared to `4511` will show 4 cows, instead of only 2.

Comment: I will be writing a method later on to make sure that there are 4 distinct numbers. I'm not sure what I'm doing, I might just start from scratch. Thank you all for your time!

Comment: OK, if you can guarantee that there are four different numbers, this is a much easier problem.  You can count the number of bulls first.  Then shove everything in a couple of sets, take their intersection, and look at the size of it.  This is the total of cows and bulls.

Answer (score 0):

Threw this together for fun (running in groovy console, possibly not perfectly valid java).

```
public static int[] getCowsBulls(int match, int guess)
{
    Character[] matchChars = Integer.toString(match).getChars();    
    Character[] guessChars = Integer.toString(guess).getChars();        
    int minLen = Math.min(matchChars.length, guessChars.length);

    Set<Character> matchSet = new HashSet<>();
    matchSet.addAll(matchChars);

    int cows = 0;
    int bulls = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < minLen; i++) {
        Character gc = guessChars[i];
        boolean inMatch = matchSet.contains(gc);
        if(!inMatch) { continue; }
        if(matchChars[i].equals(gc)) {
          bulls++;
        } else {
          cows++;
        }
    }
    return new Integer[]{ cows, bulls };
}
```